# Which algorithm solves the single-pair shortest path in a weighted directed cyclic graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, weighted-graphs, directed-graphs

I need to find the shortest path between two nodes in a directed, positively weighted graph that migt contain cycles. All weights are either zero or one. If it was not weighted, I'd use breadth-first search. Dijkstra's algorithm should solve this, but is there a more appropriate algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all distances are between $0$ and $n-1$, Dijkstra's algorithm with a suitable priority queue takes time $O(n+m)$, where $n$ and $m$ are the number of edges and vertices of the graph, respectively.

The priority queue is simply an array $A$ such that $A[i]$ contains a list of all elements with key $i$. The keys extracted during Dijkstra's algorithm correspond to distances in the graph and are always non-decreasing. Therefore to report the smallest element in the queue it suffices scan the array starting from the previous index $i$ (initially $i=0$) until an $A[i]$ that stores a non-empty list $L$  is found. Then remove any element element $x$ from $L$ and return it.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the priority queue idea. I also found out about the "0-1 breadth-first search" algorithm, do you think there's a reason to prioritise one over the other of these two?

Comment: The 0-1 breadth first algorithm is essentially the same once you realize that only two buckets of $A$ can be full at any point in time. When a vertex $v$ is extracted from "bucket" $A[i]$, it has distance $i$ from the source. All edges $(v,u)$ relaxed while considering $v$ will yield distances that are either $i$ or $i+1$. This shows that you can just keep the "current" bucket and the "next" bucket. The 0-1-BFS merges both buckets in a single list. If a vertex has distance $i$, it is added at the front of the list (i.e. in the "current") bucket. Otherwise it is appended at the end of the list.

Comment: Thank you for the insights!

Comment: It might be easier to implement 0-1-BFS since you only deal with a single list, and you don't have to keep track of $i$.